# Putting the HTTP specification aside, what is the main reason or advantage of appending the id of a resource in HTTP PUT?

Tags: asp.net, rest, http, asp.net-web-api, http-method

If I can do the following when creating a record,

URI: /api/roles/
Method: POST
Content: { Id: 0, Name: 'Admin', Description: 'Administration Role' }

**Can I just do this if I want to update a record?**

URI: /api/roles/
Method: PUT
Content: { Id: 1001, Name: 'Admin', Description: 'Administration Role' }

...because I can just get the identifier in the Id field.
Instead of doing this?

URI: /api/roles/1001
Method: PUT
Content: { Id: 1001, Name: 'Admin', Description: 'Administration Role' }

...specifying the Id value twice. By the way, I cannot remove the Id field in the content. 
**If not, why? What is the main reason or advantage of appending the id of a resource in HTTP PUT, putting the HTTP specification aside?**

Comment: generally the `id` is passed to uniquely identify a resource, and the content is used to update it's current state.I believe you are allowed to do what you want.

Comment: I think if you put the HTTP principles aside, then there is really no advantage or reason. But I think you lose clarity or ease of use of your API. Without applying the HTTP principles, nothing is stopping you from making your update operations available through a GET or POST request.

Answer (score 1):

Adding ID resource denotes one of the steps of RESTful API

You could look for further discussion here : [What is the advantage of using REST instead of non-REST HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191049/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-rest-instead-of-non-rest-http)

RESTful design principles specify HATEOAS which roughly states that interaction with an endpoint should be defined within metadata that comes with the output representation and not based on out-of-band information.

http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api

Answer (score 1):

I agree there seems to be a strange redundancy in specifying the ID in the URL as well as the request body.

As I see it, the reason is not technical, but 'cultural'.

Whenever the URL is /api/roles/ you indicate that the list is being manipulated, whereas /api/roles/{id} clearly points to the target being a list item.