# How to hide the html tag in JSF to return only JSON?

Tags: ajax, json, jsf, facelets

I'm using JSF with Facelets 1.1.14 and need to return a JSON response to a ajax request.
But I'm getting the **html** tag in response. How can I hide this, to sent only JSON data?

**Main Page**

```
<html xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
  <ui:composition template="../templates/JSONTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
      <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{myjson}" />
    </ui:define>    
  </ui:composition>
</html>
```

**Template**

```
<html xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
  <ui:insert name="content" />
</html>
```

Note:a templateless solution is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

I just removed the xhtml file and navigation-case in faces-config.xml.
Then I intercept response and write directly my json string.

```
// code in MyBean.java
getResponse().getWriter().append(getMyJSON());
return null;
```

As BalusC said, the better option is use JAX-RS, but I need a faster solution to develop.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `<html>` tag.

```
<ui:composition template="../templates/JSONTemplate.xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{myjson}" />
    </ui:define>    
</ui:composition>
```

and

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <ui:insert name="content" />
</ui:composition>
```

As to a templateless solution, use JAX-RS instead of JSF. JSF is a web MVC framework, not a web service framework.

#### See also:

- [JSF + JSON: Output "plain" text in servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358006/jsf-json-output-plain-text-in-servlet)

Comment: Tks a lot, but I'm still getting the close tag
(</html>)

Comment: Well, that'll be still in the template or a misinterpretation of the actual response.