# JSTL function to replace quote chars inside a string?

Tags: string, replace, jstl, el

What is the simplest way to replace quote characters with \" sequence inside string values?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That'll be the [`fn:replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/replace.fn.html) function.

```
<%@taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
...
${fn:replace(foo, '"', '\\"')}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete question, this is an often recurring requirement in order to prevent malformed HTML when redisplaying user controlled input as a HTML attribute. *Normally*, you should use [`<c:out>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/out.html) or [`fn:escapeXml()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) for this instead. E.g.

```
<input name="foo" value="<c:out value="${param.foo}" />" />
<input name="foo" value="${fn:escapeXml(param.foo)}" />
```

It not only takes quotes into account, but also all other XML special characters like `<`, `>`, `&`, etc.

#### See also:

- [XSS prevention in JSP/Servlet web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658922/xss-prevention-in-java)

Comment: I am creating JSON with JSP, so the direct requirement is to escape quotes. Some data is used to display on page later so it may also require HTML escaping too. Thanks for a link!

Comment: I'd rather use a fullworthy JSON tool and for sure not do the job in a JSP. Start here for some concrete examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax Or if your environment allows it, go for a JAX-RS webservice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874695/servlet-vs-restful

Answer (score -7):

Use javascript replace (with /g to replace all occurrences)

```
string.replace(/"/g, '\\"')
```

Comment: I am on server-sine, in JSP file, can't pass to JS