# How to use both single and double quotes inside JSTL/EL expression?

Tags: escaping, jstl, el, quotes

I want to call fn:replace inside EL inside c:out to replace quote caracters.

The following does not work

```
<c:out value="${fn:replace(userName,'"','\\"')}"/>
```

because XML parser stops at first double quote and sees no c:cout tag termination (JSP compilation stage error).

The following

```
<c:out value="${fn:replace(userName,'&quot;','\\&quot;')}"/>
```

does not work, probably because replace function does not see actual quote character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parameterize them with `<c:set>`.

```
<c:set var="search" value='"' />
<c:set var="replace" value='\\"' />
<c:out value="${fn:replace(userName, search, replace)}"/>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete question, have you still not [considered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8898166/157882) a real JSON generator? With for example Gson it's a matter of the following oneliner, given that `user` is a fullworthy Javabean:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(user);
```

You'll get syntactically valid JSON directly without fiddling all ways to get JSP/JSTL/EL to produce valid JSON.

Comment: Yes, thanks will probably use it. Was wondering anyway if JSTL/EL has such a feature lack.

Comment: Maybe you're just using the wrong tool for the job ;) JSP is merely a view technology designed to generate **HTML** dynamically. JSTL/EL are streamlined to suit that purpose.

Comment: Hm... Sometimes I generate JSONs in iterating loop... I am sure Gson can handle this but am not feel it will be beautiful to collect data in temporary objects before sending... Also I am generating not only json but xml also... hence it was an idea to have a bunch of JSPs for all these interactions...

Comment: I don't think this is my fault that they didn't think how to escape quotes in quotes :) Also if JSP is for html only then what for they have created a content-type tag?

Comment: Also XML? For that JAX-RS was invented. Caching can just be delegated to persistence layer.

Comment: So what advantages over JSPs it has in situation like mine -- to have few adaptor services for different clients?

Comment: Check the JAX-RS example in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874695/servlet-vs-restful/7875851#7875851

Comment: It looks good if all sides are under my control. For the case I need create predefined textual representation from predefined java objects it looks overcomplexed.