# Double quote inside c:set (JSTL)

Tags: java, html, jsp, escaping, jstl

With **JSTL** I have to build an array (in string format) and then pass it to a Javascript function.

My gol is to have a string like this: **"abc","ghjh","fsd"**

I started doing something like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
       <c:set var="array">${array}"${item.value}"</c:set>       
</c:forEach>

<script>
var sliderLinks = [<c:out value="${array}"/>];
</script>
```

But when I see the source code of the instead of **"** I have  `&#034;`

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898815/how-to-use-both-single-and-double-quotes-inside-jstl-el-expression/8899144#8899144) but I keep on getting the same problem.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push the items into the array one by one:

```
<script>
    var sliderLinks = new Array();
    <c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
        sliderLinks.push(${item.value});
    </c:forEach>
</script>
```