# escaping quote in JSTL

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jstl

i have a variable called `param`, which has the value `I told \"I will come\"`, in JSP am assigning this to a input tag's value  as

```
<input type="text" value="${param}"/>
```

what is happening is that the value am getting is `I told \`, i.e am getting value only till the first ", but am escaping this " with a \,but still am getting this. how can I solve this?

Comment: You're escaping it in the JSTL, but the generated HTML will still be `value="I told "I will come""`. You need to escape it in the HTML using the `\"`, so your JSTL variable will likely need to be: I told \\"I will come\\".

Comment: @AnthonyGrist How can I achieve that? should i do while I assign the value to variable by saying something like &quot

Comment: This is something that `fn:escapeXml()` *should* do, but I'm not sure it does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JSTL function to replace quote chars inside a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898093/jstl-function-to-replace-quote-chars-inside-a-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" value="${fn:escapeXml(param)}"/>
```

That will work when the escaping you need is in fact XML/HTML escaping. If you're dropping the JSTL/EL expression into JavaScript code, however, that's probably not what you want. In that case you'd want a JSON encoding function, of which there are several available I think (from Google at least). (I've got my own so I can't provide direct information.)

Comment: After trying you solution I am getting the text box value as         I told \"I will come\"

Comment: @VeeruAS well that's what you said the string *contains*, so that seems like the right value.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with the Core library of JSTL, this also does the trick:

```xml
<c:out value="${param}" />
```