# How to access javascript variable in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

How can i use javascript variable inside `${}` jsp code?

below is the javascript:

```
var temp=$("#kpiSelectetor")[0].selectedIndex;
var json =JSON.parse("${savedkpiz.get(temp).kpi.replace("\"","\\\"")}") //how can i use temp here?
```

i want to use `temp` JS variables obtained in 1st line in second line. how can i do it?

Comment: It looks like you have a small, but crucial misunderstanding; JS = clientside; JSP = serverside. There is no (direct) way for both to use the same variables. You would have to use something like AJAX for this.

Comment: @Sirko i am asking if still there is a way? as you can see above ${jsp} is used in JS so may be there is a reverse way

Comment: You can send it to the server doing a form submit or via ajax. In jQuery, do $.post() (look it up in the jQuery documentation).

Comment: Not directly with this code. Have a look at AJAX for an approach. In your case, however, I think, that restructuring your code (and using more JavaScript instead of JSP) would be a better solution.

Comment: @people why votedown??

Answer (score 0):

How about assigning it to a variable first?

```
var temp = $("#kpiSelectetor")[0].selectedIndex;
var elVariable = "${savedkpiz.get(temp).kpi}";
var json = JSON.parse(elVariable.replace("\"", "\\\""));
```

You could also use a [JSTL function to do the replace](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/replace.fn.html):

```
var temp = $("#kpiSelectetor")[0].selectedIndex;
var json = JSON.parse("${fn:replace(savedkpiz.get(temp).kpi, '"', '\\"')}");
```

Also see:

- [JSTL function to replace quote chars inside a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898093/jstl-function-to-replace-quote-chars-inside-a-string)