# How to generate JSON response from JSF?

Tags: json, jsf

I have created a page where I want to get the JSON response from a JSF page, 
but when i try to get page it shows me whole html page.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title></head><body>
[{"value": "21", "name": "Mick Jagger"},{"value": "43", "name": "Johnny Storm"},{"value": "46", "name": "Richard Hatch"},{"value": "54", "name": "Kelly Slater"},{"value": "55", "name": "Rudy Hamilton"},{"value": "79", "name": "Michael Jordan"}]

</body></html>
```

Comment: If using Spring you can return JSON directly from the controller endpoints through Jackson. If not using Spring, the same approach can be taken.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

JSF is a MVC framework generating HTML, not some kind of a REST web service framework. You're essentially abusing JSF as a web service. Your concrete problem is simply caused by placing `<html>` tags and so on in the view file *yourself*.

If you really insist, then you can always achieve this by using `<ui:composition>` instead of `<html>`. You also need to make sure that the right content type of `application/json` is been used, this defaults in JSF namely to `text/html`.

```html
<ui:composition
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.renderJson}" />
</ui:composition>
```

with

```
public void renderJson() throws IOException {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    externalContext.setResponseContentType("application/json");
    externalContext.setResponseCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    externalContext.getResponseOutputWriter().write(someJsonString);
    facesContext.responseComplete();
}
```

But I strongly recommend to look at JAX-RS or JAX-WS instead of abusing JSF as a JSON web service. Use the right tool for the job.

#### See also:

- [How to implement JAX-RS RESTful service in JSF framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982657/how-to-implement-jax-rs-restful-service-in-jsf-framework/)
- [Servlet vs RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874695/servlet-vs-restful)
- [What is the need of JSF, when UI can be achieved from CSS, HTML, JavaScript, jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421839/what-is-the-need-of-jsf-when-ui-can-be-achieved-from-css-html-javascript-jquery)

Comment: thank you, your solution saved me.In real i wanted to serve some complex data as json which was not easily possible without managedBean. I tried servlet but it became complex to use webservice with it.

Comment: A servlet is easier if you just use a JSON library instead of fiddling/building it yourself. See also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax

Comment: As always, @BalusC, stacks of thanks for sharing your knowledge on Java, JSF, Servlets and general best practices.  Informative, concise and ultra informative, you get a gold star (and an up vote) today!

Comment: @Jitendra, If this is the desired answer, please accept it.

Comment: @BalusC Please tell me how can I gzip this response, I also need to check accept-encoding request header to ensure compatibility.

Comment: _I tried servlet but it became complex to use webservice with it_. It is not complex. You must define another `servlet` tag in web.xml and configure it for JAX-RS.

Answer (score 4):

I'm even using contentType="text/xhtml" with JSF 2.2 and it works great. No needs in renderJson() from the BalusC's answer above

```
<f:view encoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
 <h:outputText value="#{stationView.getClosestStationen(param.longitude, param.latitude)}" escape="false"/>
</f:view>
```

Ajax call:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: requestContextPath + '/rest/stationen.xhtml',
            type: "GET",
            data: {
               "longitude": x,
               "latitude": y
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
              $.each(data, function (i, station) {
                 ...
              });
            },
            error: function () {
                ...
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using jsf for that?  Use a servlet for serving your JSON.  My suggestion would be to use a jaxrs implementation, like cxf.

Comment: thnx for the reply.. I tried that but because of some complexity that didnot worked..

Answer (score 3):

I used just a facelet for the output (but JSF 1.2)

```
<f:view contentType="application/json" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<h:outputText value="#{someBean.getJson()}" escape="false"/>
</f:view>
```