# not able to integrate gauge.js with jsf page(primefaces)

Tags: json, jsf-2, primefaces, gauge

I want to use [gauge.js](https://github.com/bernii/gauge.js) with my jsf(primefaces) application. I dealt with primefaces components (for which, doesn't require integration) so far. Now, I want to access class property (probably through Json response) from jsf page for generating **gauage**. I read a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982762/how-to-generate-json-response-from-jsf) which suggests to generate json Response but I didn't get it properly. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Z2z2/) by bernii shows that it requires a dynamic value for creating gauge.

```
<------sampleClass------>
   public int func(){
      return aValue; }

<-----JSF----->
<canvas id="gauge"></canvas>

<------Script----->
var gaugeTarget = document.getElementById('gauge');
var gauge = new Gauge(gaugeTwoTarget);
gaugeTwo.maxValue = 100;
gaugeTwo.set(); //how can i get value return by func() here...........
```

Also [BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html) wrote awesome article on it(Java/JSP/JSF and JavaScript). Again m not able to implement it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I missed that part in your question regarding the *other* solution...

---

**Anyway** you can also solve it with a hidden field in your page...

**Bean** (your bean clas)

```
int theValue;//add getter and setter

@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    theValue = func();  
}
```

**Page** (your xhtml)

```
<h:inputText id="myFuncValueId" value="#{myBean.theValue}" style="display:none"/>
```

**js**

```
gaugeTwo.set(document.getElementById('myFuncValueId').value);
```

Comment: k.. it works but i think there may be a better idea to access it as i said..through json so that It will help me in other problems also.. Can u suggest me as told in ans http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982762/how-to-generate-json-response-from-jsf

Comment: yes, I know the technique but don't know much about FacesContext. So may be my quest become vague. Sorry for that...But i will go for another solution for which i still don't have much idea

Comment: Ohh... Oki , I missed that part in your question regarding the *other* solution...

Comment: take a look at this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax