# Write JSON to HTTP response in JSF

Tags: javascript, json, jsf, servlets, httpresponse

I want to create dynamically charts with de JavaScript Library "D3.js" in JSF. I mean with dynamically that a java methods takes data from the DB and writes a corresponding JSON. This method I have already programmed and it works. Then the JavaScript should access to the JSON and create the chart.

My question is: How to pass the JSON sting/file to the JavaScript. I think the best way is to write it in the HTTP response. But how to do that in JSF? Or do you have other suggestions?

Comment: Why 'jsf' for this? What not a simple rest service?

Comment: @Kukeltje because I write the JSON in java.

Comment: jax-rs (the java rest service implementation) **IS**  java...  Please take a step back from development and learn some basics about the technologies you intend to use. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982657/how-to-implement-jax-rs-restful-service-in-jsf-framework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just let JSF print out the JSON string as if it's a JS variable.

```
<script>var data = #{bean.json};</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, simpler than mine.

Answer (score 2):

Step by step:

- Create a backing bean method for updating a String attribute (jsonData) with the numerical array string JSON representation. You will have to:

  - Call to an EJB bean or JAX-RS service that returns the data.
  - Read the data in a List.
  - Convert the List collection to a JSON object and then stringify it, for example using the javax.json package from the standard.
  - Update the jsonData model attribute.
- In the JSF page you have to include an outputLabel component binded to the jsonData attribute. You can hide it with CSS.
- In the JSF page write Javascript code to put the component value in a Javascript variable. You can achieve it with a jQuery selector or in plain Javascript with getElementById function.
- Finally you use the Javascript variable in the D3 library.

Note: The use of D3 libraty has been copied from [here](http://vegibit.com/create-a-bar-chart-with-d3-javascript/).

The code in the JSF page would be similar to this:

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:outputLabel id="myLink" value="#{yourBackingBean.jsonData}"  
        style="display:none;" styleClass="myLink"/>

    <div class="someclass">
        <h2>Create A Bar Chart With D3 JavaScript</h2>
        <div id="bar-chart">

        </div>
    </div>  

    <script>

        var chartdata = eval(document.getElementById("myForm:myLink").innerHTML);
        // you can use jQuery too: $(".myLink").html()

        //  the size of the overall svg element
        var height = 200,
            width = 720,

        //  the width of each bar and the offset between each bar
            barWidth = 40,
            barOffset = 20;


        d3.select('#bar-chart').append('svg')
          .attr('width', width)
          .attr('height', height)
          .style('background', '#dff0d8')
          .selectAll('rect').data(chartdata)
          .enter().append('rect')
            .style({'fill': '#3c763d', 'stroke': '#d6e9c6', 'stroke-width': '5'})
            .attr('width', barWidth)
            .attr('height', function (data) {
                return data;
            })
            .attr('x', function (data, i) {
                return i * (barWidth + barOffset);
            })
            .attr('y', function (data) {
                return height - data;
            });     
    </script>
</h:form>
```