# JSF Managed bean as Webservice

Tags: jsf

I want to make JSF beans to be used both for UI as well as webservices? Is it possible? If so can you please help me to show some articles that guides me in that direction?

Comment: Can you please show some evidence of what you have researched so far?  Also please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hence the question, if I know what I need to do, I would not come here.

Comment: Can you clarify the question ? You want for example a managed bean to be associated with a REST url ? If so you can take advantage of CDI injection.

Comment: JSF managed beans and a webservices are two different front-end 'technologies'. Extract the real service and have both a webservice and a managed bean call that service (there is a duplicate of this question with detailed explanations, but I cannot seem to find it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement JAX-RS RESTful service in JSF framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982657/how-to-implement-jax-rs-restful-service-in-jsf-framework)