# How to expose data as webservice inside JSF2.2 project?

Tags: java, web-services, jsf

I'm developping an application that expose some data from database as Restful webservice(jersey plugin based) to be consumed by a mobile app. The problem is that my project is a JSF 2.2 framework based, and when I add the jersey dependencies jars to the build path and try to run the app as a web app with wildfly 10 I got many errors in the console and the application doesn't deployed in the server I really didn't understand why with jersey dependencies The JSF app is not able to run and to consume some ws resources.

I have tried to add the requested jars when the server is crashed and always seem to end up having errors in the console.

This is a console overview

```
01:44:54,763 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread
Pool -- 70) MSC000001: Failed to start service
jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSFWebService:
org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSFWebService:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/binding/BindingBuilder  at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)    at
org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320) Caused by:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/binding/BindingBuilder  at
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:356)
    at
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$WrappingResourceConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1050)
    at
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.forApplicationClass(ResourceConfig.java:348)
    at
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer.addServletWithDefaultConfiguration(JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java:245)
    at
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer.onStartupImpl(JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java:183)
    at
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(JerseyServletContainerInitializer.java:144)
    at
io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:186)
    at
io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:171)
    at
io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at
io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at
io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at
io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:234)
    at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.BindingBuilder from [Module
"deployment.JSFWebService.war:main" from Service Module Loader]     at
org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at
org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 24 more

01:44:54,776 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation]
(Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed -
address: ([("deployment" ="JSFWebService.war")]) - failure
description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" ={"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSFWebService"
="org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSFWebService:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/binding/BindingBuilder
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/binding/BindingBuilder
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.BindingBuilder from [Module
\"deployment.JSFWebService.war:main\" from Service Module Loader]"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" =["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSFWebService"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" =undefined } 01:44:54,854 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService
Thread Pool -- 34) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "JSFWebService.war"
(runtime-name : "JSFWebService.war") 01:44:54,916 INFO 
[org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0183:
Service status report WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:  
service
jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSFWebService:
org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./JSFWebService:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/binding/BindingBuilder
```

Thanks for support.

Comment: The same way you would and should do it in a non-jsf project. Create a service (technology independent) and create a front-end in rest like you would a jsf controller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement JAX-RS RESTful service in JSF framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982657/how-to-implement-jax-rs-restful-service-in-jsf-framework)

Comment: @kukeltje that's mean to add a simple java beans without any managed bean  and make this java class as a webservice resources ?But the problem is the jsf app isn't able to run as server anymore when I add jersey dependency and call the servlet class in the web.xml