# Parse JSON array of objects to Java list of beans

Tags: java, json, list

I have a JSON array of objects in a `String` variable:

```
String response = target.path("flight").path("lufthansa").request().get(String.class);
```

It looks like below:

```
[
  {
    "flightNo": "AA65",
    "flightName": "Lufthansa Airlines",
    "departingFrom": "Beruit",
    "arrivingAt": "Heathrow Airport",
    "departureTime": "10-11-2015",
    "arrivalTime": "10-11-2015",
    "cost": 45000.0
  }
]
```

How can I parse it to a `List<FlightBean>`?

```
List<FlightBean> flightInfo = new ArrayList<FlightBean>();
```

Comment: Browsers are completely unaware of anything like JSF and/or JAX-RS. What problem are you experiencing while sending a response received from a service? I would prefer a service class to receive a response from a (web) service so that it can then be consumed by JSF in a way that normally JSF uses to communicate with a service class.

Comment: @Tiny, Thanks. That's right. I did all that. i just showed a snippet where the challenge is for me. How do i parse the reponse am getting at the console into form that i can display on the browser. I want to display it in some tabular form

Comment: Parsing a JSON response is the job of an appropriate object mapper like Jackson, Google Gson. Once you map the response to an appropriate object type like a collection / map / array, it can be used in a normal Java way.

Comment: Pls could you show an example. I've been on this for so long. I felt there's no need for such mappers as Gson and all since the response is already in json format.

Comment: `JSON.parse(jsonMsg)` (and `JSON.stringify(value/object)`) can be used on the client-side, if you need not map the JSON response to a Java collection on the server side.

Comment: Thanks again but i suppose you are better at JSF and you know i would need to populate the bean with the response to display. I want to  map it to some collection on the server side. Am updating my code so you can see what am doing

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10982930/1391249) especially the caution at the end of the answer. You can instead easily map the JSON response to a Java collection using an object mapper and use that collection in a normal Java way. (Using Gson, for example is basically the matter of doing `new Gson(). fromJson(JsonElement json, Class<T> clazz)`).

Comment: @BalusC. Yes i was able to display the raw json response on the browser but i want to be able to parse and response and display it in an HTML table

Comment: @Tiny, I tried your solution of using new Gson().fromJson(JsonElement json, Class<T> clazz). It gave errors saying it expected a Json object but an array is given. Recall the response is an array not an object

Comment: So you basically want to convert JSON to Java? That part has nothing to do with JSF nor with REST services. I fixed the wrong question so you get the right attention.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for that