# How to implement AJAX using jQuery.post in JSF?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I'm trying to send some data from my jsf page to the server using `jQuery.post`. I have put the url of the same page as the url for handling the request. I'm able to get the data but not able to send a response back to my `jQuery.post` call.

My pseudo code:

```
jQuery.post('localhost/mypage.jsf', { data: 'xyz' }, function(res){
    console.log(res);
});
```

I'm able to get the `data` variable in my handler class, but not able to send back a response.

Any ideas on how I can do it better?

Answer (score 1):

JSF is basically the wrong tool for the job. You should be using a web service framework like JAX-RS instead of a component based MVC framework like JSF.

But if you really insist, you could abuse JSF the following way to send an arbitrary response back. Make use of `<f:event type="preRenderView">` in the view to invoke a method before the view is rendered and `<f:viewParam>` to set request parameters as bean properties (note that this effectively also works on GET requests).

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="data" value="#{bean.data}" />
    <f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.process}" />
</f:metadata>
```

With something like the following if you intend to return JSON with help of [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or something:

```
public void process() throws IOException {
    String message = "Hello! You have sent the following data: " + data;
    String json = new Gson().toJson(Collections.singletonMap("message", message));

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext ec = context.getExternalContext();
    ec.setResponseContentType("application/json");
    ec.setResponseCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    ec.getResponseOutputWriter().write(json);
    context.responseComplete(); // Prevent JSF from rendering the view.
}
```

Again, you're abusing JSF as the wrong tool for the job. Look at JAX-RS or maybe even a plain vanilla servlet. See also [Servlet vs RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874695/servlet-vs-restful).