# Is Jersey ServletContainer the same as DispatcherServlet?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, jersey

Does Jersey ServletContainer class play the same role as DispatcherServlet class in Spring MVC? If not, what does it do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confusion between HttpServlet class and using it with Jersey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713752/confusion-between-httpservlet-class-and-using-it-with-jersey)

Comment: Yeah, I'd say they're analogous. They're both the entry point (servlets) to the request handling. That's probably the only thing they have in common.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Both org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer in Jersey implementation of JAX-RS and org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet in Spring-REST serve as a central servlet to provide an algorithm for incoming REST request processing, while actual work is performed by configurable, delegate components in the application.