# Difference Between RestAPI and Restful webservices

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, rest, servlets

I am new to web-services. Could someone help me in understanding the difference between REST API and a Restful web-service in java. I have developed a web-application which is based on only servlets and jsp. Now the same application has to be developed using REST API. What is the difference between developing a web app with just servlets and jsp and developing a webapp with REST API. Can someone provide links to good tutorials where I can learn more about REST API with samples.

Comment: The difference? The amount of code you need to write yourself.

Comment: Here is a list with REST API with samples [https://www.google.co.uk/#q=REST+API+with+samples] Here

Comment: Related question (which is I think after all the same as you're trying to ask, but then much better phrased): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874695/servlet-vs-restful/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.That implies RestAPI and Restful webservices are one and the same.As am new to technology I could not phrase the question properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A RESTful web API (also called a RESTful web service) is a web API implemented using HTTP and REST principles. It is a collection of resources
```

Reference : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Sometimes, some organization might show little difference, Between REST API and  Restful web services.
For eg, Rest API might be common for everyone to use the data with same endpoint.

Restful web services may comes with custom modification for specific requirement and endpoint will be different.

Comment: :Thanks Viji.suppose am developing a webapplication in which I start an executable file from webpage instead of command line. This am doing by using Runtime.getExec() method using servlets. Can the same functionality be developed using REST API. Please let me know if I need to put this as a seperate question

Comment: Yes you can do it in web service and again, its depends on what response you want.

Comment: :Let us say that when I start the .exe file from webpage it gets started and show details like-.exe file is started and its status,like if it is active or shutdown

Comment: :Thanks for the quick reply. I appreciate it.