# URL Routes with Java Servlets

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jsp, servlets

I wanted to know if there is a way to do similar code in java servlet like I do in express.js

In express I can say for example:

```js
    app.get('/:name',function(bla bla)){}
```

the `:/name` its a parameter in which the url of the get can be

```
    localhost/kevin
    localhost/joe
```

or whatever... This is great because I can take then for example that name `(request.params.name)` and so something with it. And it is also great because there is no limit(As far as I know) as to how many routes I can create, it just serves as a placeholder.

Is there a way I can do this using Java servlets?? I want to be able to have an html page that when I click a button it goes to `localhost/button1` If I click another button it goes to `localhost/button2`.. and so on.. But also I'm letting the user create buttons dynamically so I don't want to create jsp pages beforehand, I just want the servletto create one..?

Thanks

Comment: Kevin, you could look at using JAX_RS which is used for developing RESTFUL java/j2ee applications.  https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepu.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost. With help of a prefix mapping `/foo/*` and [`HttpServletRequest#getPathInfo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo()).

```
@WebServlet("/name/*")
public class NameServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name = request.getPathInfo().substring(1);
        // ...
    }

}
```

Invoke it as

- http://localhost:8080/context/name/kevin
- http://localhost:8080/context/name/joe
- ...

You can optionally map the servlet on `/*`, but then it will act like a global front controller which isn't necessarily a good idea as you'd have to take static resources like CSS/JS/images and such into account.

In case you actually intend to create a REST service, rather look at JAX-RS instead of "plain vanilla" servlets. It would further reduce boilerplate code. See also a.o. [Servlet vs RESTful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7874695/servlet-vs-restful).

Comment: So I'm having trouble doing this.. My servlet runs here: http://localhost:8080/demo/servlet/login If I go there I have like some text displayed so I see that it is working.. I added what you gave me but if I do http://localhost:8080/demo/servlet/login/name/kevin it cant find that link or if i do http://localhost:8080/demo/servlet/login/name also cant find it... any ideas? Also my mapping in web.xml (url-pattern) is: /servlet/login   Maybe change something there? the name of the servlet is login

Comment: If you intend to use exactly those URLs, and the context path is `/demo`, then the URL pattern must be `/servlet/login/name/*` (which is quite awkward, but that aside). The asterisk is important. The actual servlet name is irrelevant to this all.

Comment: It worked! I had to change something on my web.xml (deleted the servlet map url thing) and ran it in localhost/'contextpath'/'nameofservlet'/name/kevin   Thanks!