# non-RESTful vs. RESTful

Tags: rest, network-programming, server

I am really new to programming, and having some trouble understanding the concept of RESTful APIs. I've read about REST and RESTful APIs. I've looked through the questions already asked here in SO, but can't seem to get any better understanding of the subject.

In my network programming class I'm working with socket programming. There are two parts, part A and part B, in the task.

In part A I've programmed a server that responds to GET and POST. The server either retrieves the file asked for by the client, or writes to the file. (HTTP-protocol is used).

In part B I'm to use HTTP to implement a RESTful application. Basically it is a message server with the ability to handle GET, POST, PUT and DELETE. In this part the server is to create and interact with an xml-file.  I understand how the methods work. But what I really don't understand is the following:

Why is the server in part A non-RESTful, while it is RESFTful in part B?

Comment: Actually its very easy... RESTful means you are Using the REST-API and in Part B you are obviously using REST that means you are RESTful

Comment: This might sound a bit dumb, but why isn't the server in part A considered RESTful? Anything to do with the way the two different servers are responding? Or the requests they handle? I really can't seem to get this..

Comment: Basically, Server A can be restful, and server B can be non restful with same specification you have mentioned. it is not about these specification but how these specification implemented. If you chose rest approach to impelement this specification, it is restful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in part A, what you wrote was just a HTTP end point. Its not a REST 'service'. Maybe you can check this link out for more explanation :
[What is the difference between HTTP and REST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190836/what-is-the-difference-between-http-and-rest) 
Also, this link provides more info related to that - [What is the advantage of using REST instead of non-REST HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191049/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-rest-instead-of-non-rest-http)

Answer (score 24):

**REST** is an architectural style (not a protocol like SOAP, not a technology itself or even not an implementation, it is basically a set of a rule), This architecture offers some constraints for using HTTP. If you stick by this architectural constraints while using HTTP, it is called **RESTful**, otherwise, it is **not-RESTful**.

list of these architectural constraints [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Architectural_constraints). 
resource and more details [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)