# In MVC the deleting a record can be achieved by POST, so whats the need of DELETE verb?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http

Deletion can be achieved through HTTP POST, so why do we need a separate HTTP verb called DELETE?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [REST API - why use PUT DELETE POST GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573305/rest-api-why-use-put-delete-post-get) **and** [Use POST for delete/update in Rest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46167855/use-post-for-delete-update-in-rest)

Comment: This is not related to MVC, but to HTTP methods.

Answer (score 1):

To quote Jurassic Park:

[image]

Having a `DELETE` verb is a convention. It makes your API easily exploitable and self-descriptive.

Technically, you could just use a `GET` verb with a `action=` and `data=` URL parameters to do any CRUD operation, but that would be unintuitive, making your application hard to use (and to maintain!) by anyone other than yourself.